# T-SQL Child id's to match Parent id

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have some orphaned records that I need to make into Parent records but first I need subsequent records based on the UserName to have the id of the first instance of the username which afterwards I will change into a parent record, I've got this so far:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 

(
ID INT
,UserName NVARCHAR(30)
,FileID INT



)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1,'TT',1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2,'TT',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3,'TT',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4,'WW',4)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5,'WW',5)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6,'WW',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (7,'WW',7)
;
WITH CTE
 AS
 (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by UserName Order by UserName) RN

    from @Test
 )
 SELECT *
  FROM CTE
  ORDER BY Id ASC
```

[image]

And I'm looking to get this :
[image]

```
ID  UserName    FileID  RN
1   TT           1      1
2   TT           1      2
3   TT           1      3
4   WW           4      1
5   WW           4      2
6   WW           4      3
7   WW           4      4
```

I'm looking to update the ID column from :

```
ID  UserName    FileID
627    TT             626
628    TT             626
629    TT             626
461    WW             460
462    WW             460
463    WW             460
464    WW             460
```

To this :

```
ID  UserName    FileID
627  TT          627
628  TT          627
629  TT          627
461  WW          461
462  WW          461
463  WW          461
464  WW          461
```

Comment: please enter expected result as text

Answer (score 0):

use Rank

```
WITH CTE
 AS
 (
    SELECT ID,USERNAME,RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY USERNAME) AS FILEID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USERNAME Order by UserName) RN

    from @Test
 )
 SELECT *
  FROM CTE
  ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: Its Kind of what I'm trying to do but not, I should have said I need to update the FileID from say :

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I try it with different numbers see above, it stays at what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 

(
ID INT
,UserName NVARCHAR(30)
,FileID INT



)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (627,'TT',626)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (628,'TT',626)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (629,'TT',626)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (461,'WW',460)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (462,'WW',460)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (463,'WW',460)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (464,'WW',460)
;

UPDATE  T
SET FILEID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @Test TT WHERE T.FILEID = TT.FILEID)
FROM @Test T;

SELECT * FROM @Test ORDER BY ID
```

Results:

```
ID   UserName   FileID
461     WW       461
462     WW       461
463     WW       461
464     WW       461
627     TT       627
628     TT       627
629     TT       627
```